# How to test Mobile app push notification capabilities in an emulator?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cordova, telerik

Is it possible to test push notification in mobile apps, such as android & ios, with an emulator rather than a physical device?

In this ( http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/sample-apps/sample-backend-services-pushnotifications ) article, I learned that such testing was not possible from within the emulator. During a quick Google search, I noticed many other push-notification services couldn't be tested in the emulator.

I would like to be able to be able to test the push-notification feature without needing to posses a physical device, because I can't afford them.

Comment: Seems parse does support push notifications to emulators https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**iOS**

You **cannot** test real push notifications on iOS Simulator because it does not support it. You would get this error if you tried to register for remote notifications:

> NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "Remote notifications are not supported
>   in the simulator"

You should try to debug the app on real device not on the simulator. However you can mock push notifications on iOS using this [library](https://github.com/acoomans/SimulatorRemoteNotifications).

**Android**

The Android emulator **is capable** of receiving push notifications through GCM, however, it does require an additional step of actually logging a valid Google account into the emulator when it is running. This will need to be done for each emulator that you wish to use with push notifications through GCM.

Comment: What do I need to do to log into a Google account in the emulator?  On the emulator, under settings, I see an option for "accounts," but this appears to be e-mail only because the choice is between IMAP and Exchange.

Comment: You probably need to use a Google APIs target when you create your AVD.

Comment: IOS now allows test push notifications on Simulators from xcode 11.4 upwords https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes

Comment: I believe also Google Play app is needed, and it isn't always available. I installed Google APIs and no Google Play, now download the one which has Google Play specified (not available for all devices)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone runs across this post (it was a top hit for me searching for similar information) looking to do this in a more modern (than 2014) Xcode environment: YES, it is possible to do this in iOS simulator now!  [This page](https://lickability.com/blog/testing-push-notifications-in-the-simulator/) has a great tutorial on how to do so.

Quick summary: create a JSON-formatted text file containing the payload, such as

```
{
  "Simulator Target Bundle" : "com.example.app",
  "aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "title" : "push title",
        "body" : "push body"
    }
  },
  "isRead" : false,
  "createdOn" : "2021-12-01T20:14:50.3157643+00:00",
}
```

then drag and drop that file onto the simulator!